# Convert 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDateTime' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datetime

Does anyone know how to convert OracleDateTime to System.DateTime?

I was able to convert OracleNumber to double via a directcast, however does not compute with datetime?

What I have tried:

```
 Dim oDateTime As OracleDateTime = (DataRow)oRow("Date")
 Dim vDateTime As DateTime

vDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DirectCast(oDateTime, OracleDateTime))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get to a datetime by the following:

```
vDateTime = CDate(DirectCast(oDateTime, OracleDateTime))
```

Then:

```
 Dim formatDate As String = vDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```